# How to find the location of TCL procedure?

Tags: tcl, procedure

How can be find the location of procedure (function) in TCL. Under location I mean the source file in which it is declared.

I'm trying to read foreign source-code and can not find the declaration of a single procedure, example:

```
set MSISDNElement [regexp -all -inline {ISDN +[0-9]+} $Command]

if { $MSISDNElement != "" } {
    foreach elm $MSISDNElement {
        set MSISDNValue [list ISDN [getInternationalFormat [lindex $elm 1]]]
    }
}

set EptData [list [lindex $Command 1]]

InitEptData 3
foreach Element $EptData {
    SetEptData [lindex $Element 0] [lindex $Element 1]
}
```

For the functions **InitEptData** & **SetEptData** I can't find any declaration. Could someone familiar much more in deep with TCL, to explain how to solve that issue which I'm facing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general you cannot find a location for a procedure (because Tcl gives you with `eval` the ability to define it on the fly, dynamically, at runtime). In practice, you could use textual find (e.g. `grep` on Linux) to find the defining occurrence of some name.

Comment: Also, some procedures are actually defined by some executable code compiled from C.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Yes, this is the case here! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no generic answer to this, as Tcl allows you to declare procedures on the fly, so they could have no actual file reference.

There are some attempts to improve the situation for procs that have a defining file, for example [TIP280](http://www.tcl.tk/cgi-bin/tct/tip/280.html), which is actually available as `info frame`in recent 8.5 versions, and TIP 86, which is only in discussion.

But if a simple `grep`does not work, you could track the moment a procedure or command gets created.

This happens in various places (Tcl OO might add a few more, not sure):

- During a `load` command when a binary extension registers its command handler functions with [Tcl_CreateCommand](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/CrtCommand.htm) or the more modern Tcl_CreateObjCommand.
- During a `source` command when a file with proc definitions is loaded
- While running the `proc` command itself to define a new procedure

Using the commands `info commands` and `namespace children` you can walk the whole namespace tree to get a list of defined commands before and after the executed command. So you can create a wrapper that tracks any new commands. See http://wiki.tcl.tk/1489 for some hints how to do it.

Or, simply use a debugger like RamDebugger http://www.compassis.com/ramdebugger/Intro, or ActiveStates commercial debugger.

Comment: A short suggestion: when a new command is defined, it usually deletes the old one (`rename` throws an error instead). So a nop proc with that name and a delete trace tells you when the old command is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From the bash shell, I use:

```
 find . -name "*.tcl" -exec grep -H proc_name_to_find {} \; | grep proc
```

This finds all tcl files, then executes grep on each file to search for the proc_name_to_find, and then the output is greped once more for those lines that contain 'proc'

Since **grep -H** outputs filenames with the output string, this shows you the output you need to find the definition in your editor.

**Example**:

```
$ find . -name "*.tcl" -exec grep -H set_prime {} \; | grep proc
./my_lib.tcl:proc prime_test::set_prime {{quiet 0} {no_compare 0}} {
```

There are other solutions with xargs...

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to catch transient defined procs and maybe not renamed procs but for 99% of the time this should work and be very easy. It will also help you with sorting out the situation if you find there are two procs at the global namespace but an unexpected one is called first.

Let's say my proc is 'doBlah', I can do this:

```
    array get ::auto_index doBlah
```

Let's say I only know it contains the string 'lah', I can do this:

```
    array get ::auto_index *lah*
```

In both cases, you will get back the contents of the auto_index which tells you which file Tcl would source when you try to run that proc.