# To find the implementation of a function in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a script that is run from another tool.
The script run a function but I don't know where the implementation of this function.
My goal: To find the implementation of this function
How can I do it ?
I found command like env(TCLLIBPATH) and auto_path  but I got an message that these variables  are not defined.
The grep command doesn't help because I don't know where to search it.

Comment: If you get a message saying that the auto_path variable is not defined, you are doing something wrong. It should always exist at the global level in any normal Tcl shell.

Answer (score 0):

> To find the implementation of this function

In Tcl, you don't necessarily have to find the source definition of a `proc`, you can ask Tcl to reveal the implementation (whatever the source) using introspection. Provided you know the `proc`'s name (`foo`), use `info args` and `info body`:

```
% proc foo {a} { puts "Hello World!" }
% info args foo
a
% info body foo
 puts "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Admittedly, it depends what you want to achieve in a subsequent step. Also check out previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651549/how-to-find-the-location-of-tcl-procedure).

Comment: Do you know something equivalent to where command in unix ?@mrcalvin

Comment: There is no `where` equivalent in Tcl. But you should explain to us, why you want to find the source definition to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If the straight-forward method of looking for `source` and `package require` commands doesn't reveal where a command comes from, it may be auto-loaded. Check the auto_index array to see if that has an entry for the command. For example:

```
% array get auto_index parray
parray {source /usr/lib64/tcl/tcl8.6/parray.tcl}
% array get auto_index history
history {source /usr/lib64/tcl/tcl8.6/history.tcl}
```