# How to find the file paths of all namespace loaded in an application using tcl/TK under Unix?

Tags: path, namespaces, tcl

For existing flow, there would be a whole bunch of namespaces loaded when running some script job.
However, if I want to check & trace the usage of some command in some namespace, I need to find the script path of the certain namespace.
Is there some way to get that? Particularly, I'm talking about Primetime scripts.

Comment: Welcome! Did you search for previous answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12651549/how-to-find-the-location-of-tcl-procedure?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Technically, namespaces don't have script paths. But we can do something close enough:

```
proc report_current_file {call code result op} {
    if {$code == 0} {
        # If the [proc] call was successful...
        set cmd [lindex $call 1]
        set qualified_cmd [uplevel 1 [list namespace which $cmd]]
        set file [file normalize [info script]]
        puts "Defined $qualified_cmd in $file"
    }
}
trace add execution proc leave report_current_file
```

It's not perfect if you've got procedures creating procedures dynamically — the current file might be wrong — but that's fortunately not what most code does.

Another option that might work for you is to use `tcl::unsupported::getbytecode`, which produces a lot of information in machine-readable format (a dictionary). One of the pieces of information is the `sourcefile` key. Here's an example running interactively on my machine:

```
% parray tcl_platform
tcl_platform(byteOrder)     = littleEndian
tcl_platform(engine)        = Tcl
tcl_platform(machine)       = x86_64
tcl_platform(os)            = Darwin
tcl_platform(osVersion)     = 20.2.0
tcl_platform(pathSeparator) = :
tcl_platform(platform)      = unix
tcl_platform(pointerSize)   = 8
tcl_platform(threaded)      = 1
tcl_platform(user)          = dkf
tcl_platform(wordSize)      = 8
% dict get [tcl::unsupported::getbytecode proc parray] sourcefile
/opt/local/lib/tcl8.6/parray.tcl
```

Note that the procedure has to be already defined for this to work. And if Tcl's become confused about what file the code was in (because of dynamic programming trickery) then that key is absent.

Comment: That dictionary has all sorts of other things in it too. The exact keys it has (or format of their data) are not a part of Tcl's API that we guarantee to maintain between even minor versions… but I don't see `sourcefile` going away. That's too good to have!